# Should the Id column of a table be encrypted/hashed before sending to client

Tags: php, javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, database

I have this question in my mind.
I thought to share it with you fellows to get a suitable answer for myself and might help someone out there.

So, for argument's sake lets assume we have a users table for our website with the following columns:

```
    id, name, email and password
```

Many times we have to use the id field on the client side.
say we have implemented AJAX to allow the users to edit their profile.
and on profile editing page looks something like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
         <label>Name: <input type = "text" name = "txtName" id = "txtName"/></label>
    </div>
    <div>
         <label>Email: <input type = "text" name = "txtEmail" id = "txtEmail"/></label>
    </div>
    <div>
         <label>Password: <input type = "password" name = "txtPasswd" id = "txtPasswd"/></label>
    </div>
    <div>
         <input type = "submit" name = "updateProfile" value = "Save" />
         <input type = "hidden" name = "id" value = "1" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Please keep your focus on the question rather than pointing out flaws which can arise from the tables design, the html or css stuff.

Regards,

Comment: It depends on how dangerous it is for the user to know the ID, or to be able to guess other IDs. If I can overwrite another user's profile by changing the ID from `1` to `2`, you have a deeper problem with security. Still, people like to use random IDs to serve to the outside world

Comment: i have a hash(random 32 chars) and id for users, i use the hash for external communications the id internally.

Comment: @Dagon , it's a bad idea , because I can join your community and see the forms and easily change other user's details.

Comment: @Ofir Baruch there is no community, don't presume to know what sort of sites i build for a living.

Comment: @Dagon , I used the term `community` as a site with login and users. Anyway , didn't mean to offense.

Comment: you think I would not have the usual user name\password as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better keep the user type in session.

By user type, I mean you will have to check access/edit/update/view rights according to user types.

then showing ids to users do not have any means of revealing your database column values, as your rights checking code will overcome by redirecting or prompting user that such actions are not allowed to their user type.

One more thing if you use encrypt value for the ids, then again user can just copy and use your encrypt value for their sneaky purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I would depend on a set of authentication rules on the server as to which user is allowed to edit which record. Showing the record ID in the client is really a moot point.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to encrypt the user id, but you should check other data.  A good idea is to verify the users old password before you change a new one.  That prevents someone who has stumbled on an open account from altering it.  Another good practice is to verify that a user is logged in (say, with a session) and make sure the id matches the id of the logged in user.

That brings me to another way around this question - don't use the id at all.  Keep it handy in the session and there's no need to pass it around in forms.  That means you can only do things with the id that you're logged in with, and you may not ever know what your own id is.

Answer (score 0):

The dangerous thing is in the script which process the data.
Even as a beginner hacker I know I can change this ID and then the script might
change someone's else details.

Therfore , you shouldn't use the id as a way to know which user to edit,
you should use `Cookies` or `Sessions`

Comment: unless you're adding a hash/checksum in your cookie or sessionId cookie then the "hacker" can just as easily change that too.

Comment: Right you are. md5 or another hashing function for the password , the user's id or even the session's id should be used.